# How kafka connector works for postgresql and mysql database

Tags: mysql, postgresql, apache-kafka-connect

I'm following the quick start tutorials from here [quick-start-kafka-connect](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/)

This tutorial shows how to stream the mysql database table changes into kafka topic.

The only part is download everything and just add `/tmp/kafka-connect-jdbc-source.json` file with some config properties and start

**How does this work in background ?**

> 1 : Does it create connection with database and monitor tables for specific intervals of time? OR
>
> 2 : Does it uses replication log? (i don't know how this works)
>
> 3 : Is this same mechanism for mysql and postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debezium monitors the OpLog.

[Kafka Connect JDBC](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/index.html#connect-jdbc) by Confluent (which you've linked to) can use a time-interval, and that configuration is shared by all JDBC-compliant connections, MySQL and Postgres included.

> For incremental query modes that use timestamps, the source connector uses a configuration `timestamp.delay.interval.ms` ...

---

> replication log? (i don't know how this works)

You can find [the Debezium guide here](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#enabling-query-log-events-optional), but this mechanism differs for Mongo, Postgres, MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, etc.